# how to center my div vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've looked around and tried many different solutions, yet none of them worked for me.  Basically I am just trying to have my `<center>` tag aligned vertically, so the margin on the top is always equal to the bottom when resizing. What kind of CSS can I apply to do this?

```css
.modalText {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.paypalCenterModal {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.modalText {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.img-responsiveModal {
  margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px #888888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 modal3ImgPrev">
      <img class="img-responsiveModal" id="myImg3" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg' />
    </div>
    <center class="paypalCenterModal">
      <h3 class="modalText">Select Options</h3>
      <form class="paypalForm" <p>Form Content In Here</p>
      </form>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `margin: auto 0;`?

Comment: Please share the css properties you have used as of now. It will help us to check and assist you better.

Comment: this only aligns it horizontally @RiddhiParekh

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this. In general, one of the ways you can use is: give these properties to child div "position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);" and give "position: relative;" to parent div. But it depends what exactly the requirement is.

Comment: hmm. Just tried this and isn't working at all. Btw I added the css I have already @AKNair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get this by using **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)**.

If you are thinking to upgrade your bootstrap to **version4** you will get this easily.

And as I see you are not using bootstrap grid `col-*` and `row` classes according to doc.

> Read **[Bootstrap3 Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.v-align-section .row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.modalText {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .v-align-section .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="v-align-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 modal3ImgPrev">
        <img class="img-responsiveModal img-responsive" id="myImg3" src='http://via.placeholder.com/250x350' />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form class="paypalForm">
          <h3 class="modalText">Select Options</h3>
          <p>Form Content In Here</p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just messed around with if for a minute, and just realized that the two divs aren't stacking after being resized under the col-sm broswer size (I changed col-xs-6 to col-sm-6)

Comment: @FinsUp you have to change the flex-direction for the `xs` view..See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the bottom values in the class it self. Try the following snippet. Further more you can adjust values with using `rem` rather than `pixel` to improve the responsiveness.

```css
.divThatNeedsToBeCenteredVertically {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 modal3ImgPrev">
      <img class="img-responsiveModal" id="myImg3" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg' />
    </div>
    <center class="divThatNeedsToBeCenteredVertically">
      <h3 class="modalText">Select Options</h3>
      <form class="col-sm-6 paypalForm">
        <p>Form Content In Here</p>
      </form>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use "centre" tag? It has been obsoleted. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Below is the solution, make sure that the position of the parent div, with class name "row", is not "static" (by default, the position of div is static, you can change it to "relative" or whatever).

```
.row {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.divThatNeedsToBeCenteredVertically {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: gray;
}
```

For more details look at the URL:    https://jsfiddle.net/sanqian/y9ftobma/

Here is another example, I recommend you to having a look at it.
    https://jsfiddle.net/sanqian/La9m2u8L/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS Snippet

```
  form{
  position : absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  top : 50%;
  left : 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

We are setting the top and left to middle of the form screen

Answer (score 0):

> Try this..!

```css
.modalText {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin: auto 0;
}
.img-responsiveModal {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px #888888;
}
.row{
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    /* Firefox */
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    -moz-box-align:center;
    /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    /* W3C */
    display:box;
    box-pack:center;
    box-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 modal3ImgPrev">
           <img class="img-responsiveModal" id="myImg3" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjM2ODEzMDUzMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDQ2NzU3OQ@@._V1_UY317_CR20,0,214,317_AL__QL50.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 paypalCenterModal">
           <h3 class="modalText">Select Options</h3>
           <form class="paypalForm"><p>Form Content In Here</p></form>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```